# Spring configuration called twice and so as the Beans with Groovy Spock

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, spock

I am in the weird situation where we have test cases in java as well as groovy but eventually will move to groovy.

I have 2 abstract classes one for java and one for spock something like below.

```
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = TestProfileResolver.class)
@IntegrationTest
@IntegrationTestConfiguration(
        applicationStartUpClass = Application.class,
        additionalLocalConfigurationClasses = [LocalIntegrationTestConfiguration.class])
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = [
    LocalIntegrationTestConfiguration.class,
    NonLocalIntegrationTestConfiguration.class,
])
abstract class TestSpec extends Specification {
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = TestProfileResolver.class)
@IntegrationTest
@IntegrationTestConfiguration(
    applicationStartUpClass = Application.class,
    additionalLocalConfigurationClasses = { LocalIntegrationTestConfiguration.class, Resources.class})
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {
    LocalIntegrationTestConfiguration.class,
    NonLocalIntegrationTestConfiguration.class,
})
@Component
abstract public class Test {
}

@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({TestProperties.class})
@Import({
    Resources.class,
})
@Profile({"local"})
public class LocalIntegrationTestConfiguration {
    public LocalIntegrationTestConfiguration() {
        System.out.println(" $$$$$ LocalIntegrationTestConfiguration $$$$");
    }
}
```

Problem is LocalIntegrationTestConfiguration is called twice once by regular spring framework and then by spock framework. I want it to be called only once.

I want to reuse the configs on TEST in TESTSPEC but don't know how. Any groovy expert ?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by spring and would happen if you'd configure two junit test this way as well. The problem is that you are creating different contexts since one is using

`@IntegrationTestConfiguration(
        applicationStartUpClass = Application.class,
        additionalLocalConfigurationClasses = [LocalIntegrationTestConfiguration.class])`

and the other

`@IntegrationTestConfiguration(
    applicationStartUpClass = Application.class,
    additionalLocalConfigurationClasses = { LocalIntegrationTestConfiguration.class, Resources.class})`

note the additional `Resource.class`.

If you want spring to reuse a context then it must be configured **identical**. For more details please read the spring docs about [context caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching).

And why do you annotate your test with `@Component`?